# Which MVP frameworks exist for ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvp

Can someone provide basic sample / link for MVP Framework.

Need to design a website => is much more of Admin type site.

SQL Server as database backend.

Comment: The MVP pattern is basically MVC where the view is not able to talk to the model. So the view talks to the presenter which then talks to the model. Then the model talks to the presenter that talks to the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model View Presenter at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

MVP Framework at CodePlex:

http://www.codeplex.com/aspnetmvp

Answer (score 3):

Check out the webforms MVP framework. Might be better than rolling out your own

http://webformsmvp.com/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [WebClient Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264518.aspx) from the Microsoft Patterns & Practices team. It's also [here on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/websf). It uses the MVP pattern, and adds a couple of helpful options to Visual Studio when you install it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used with success the following open source project to implement the MVP pattern in ASP.NET + WinForms:

- Castle Project.

Take a look at my blog post which shows a complete ASP.NET Web Application sample:

[Model View Presenter pattern with Castle in ASP.NET](http://www.leniel.net/2010/02/model-view-presenter-mvp-castle-asp-net.html)

Answer (score 0):

CodeProject has a good example on how you can start with .NET MVP framework:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/DotNetMVPFramework_Part1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also look at [ASP.Net MVC](http://asp.net/mvc).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the Microsoft Prism project:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx

Here's a quickstart:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35775/Model-View-Presenter-and-Model-View-ViewModel-in-P.aspx?msg=3013396

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler has written quite a bit on various patterns used for Enterprise level software.

His website is [here](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/). He gives several variants of MVP so you can pick the one that best suited for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found "[Polymorphic Podcast : Design Patterns Bootcamp: Model View * Patterns](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/mv-patterns/)" very useful. It has several concise walkthrough videos.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this simple example which demonstrates the basics of MVP:

http://www.avantprime.com/articles/view-article/2/model-view-presenter-(mvp)-design-pattern-in-asp.net